# Customized Website Templates

Tags: html, templates, web

I have a website that I want to make available for different teams.  Basically each team can have a customer website on this site.  The website would be /mywebsite/TeamA, /mywebsite/TeamB, etc.

The site itself has a database behind it that does all the work.  However I want anyone to be able to create a website for there team by completing a bunch of questions.  All the pages in the website use the same layout, but filled in based on the team name.

I thought about creating new pages for each team, but I also want to be able to modify say the history page and have those changes impact every team (not the actual data in the database, the way it is displayed, or add new stuff).

I am stuck.  Just not sure what else to search on, or what direction to look in.  I keep trying website templates, but it does not appear to be what I want.

Thanks.

ADDITIONAL INFO

I am using php, javascript, html and sql for the site.

Let's say I have a page index.php. The layout for each team is exactly the same, logo, menu items, footer. In the middle is a content section. This is updated by the user via a admin content management page.

I have many pages that show stats, rosters, etc.

I want each team's pages to be unique with the data they enter but everything else would be the same.  Then if I wanted to add say another stat category I could add it in one place and it would be available for all teams.

Comment: wow. google cms? you have a website that is database behind it. what database? what runs your website and its database? wordpress? drupal?

Comment: Not much info you are giving us, take a look at wordpress networks.

Comment: Sorry, having a hard time explaining, which might be part of my problem searching.

I added more info to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. When a user is created by completing the questions, also make them choose a unique id that will act as part of the URL. Example "TeamB"
2. Modify your htaccess file so /mywebsite/index.php?id=TeamB is rewritten as /mywebsite/TeamB